# Encrypting a zip

Tags: java, android

I want to **Encrypt Zip file** that I generate, which contains a **files** inside it. I want to encrypt it with password.

Its my first time to work with `Encryption`. I did my own `research`, I seem to understand but not clearly on how it works.

Can anyone help with a clear example, and a good way of `encrypting` by explain to me and how do I implement it or maybe give an example.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well i have not worked much with it but look for **javax.crypto** package

Comment: I have that lib of javax.crypto already. Its my first time to work with it encrption, Currently I have  **lcrypto-jdk16-143.jar**, **lcrypto-jdk16-143**

Comment: javax.crpto is inbuilt in ur jdk and try this http://javapapers.com/java/java-symmetric-aes-encryption-decryption-using-jce/

Comment: I want to encrypt it with a password, sorry for not mentioning that on my question, I see your link is encrypting Strings, I want to encrypt a zipped file, will that code work if I also want to encrypt a zip file?

Comment: First off all , work in crypt at **byte** level . so the **file extension** wont matter... Zip readers cannot read your java emcrypted files ! **(EXCEPTION: you are talking about a zip tool say winzip giving its predefined password prompt to open the fine. My comments dont cover this aspect)**

Comment: Okay I get your point, thanks anyway with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `CipherOutputStream` like this:

```
public static void encryptAndClose(FileInputStream fis, FileOutputStream fos) 
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {

    // Length is 16 byte
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("1234567890123456".getBytes(), "AES");
    // Create cipher
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);      

    // Wrap the output stream for encoding
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);       

    //wrap output with buffer stream
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(cos);     

    //wrap input with buffer stream
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis); 

    // Write bytes
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = bis.read(d)) != -1) {
        bos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    // Flush and close streams.
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    bis.close();
}


public static void decryptAndClose(FileInputStream fis, FileOutputStream fos) 
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {

    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("1234567890123456".getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);

    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);

    //wrap input with buffer stream
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(cis); 

    //wrap output with buffer stream
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);       

    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = bis.read(d)) != -1) {
        bos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    bis.close();
}
```

I use it like this:

```
File output= new File(outDir, outFilename);

File input= new File(inDir, inFilename);

if (input.exists()) {

FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(input);
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(output);

encryptAndClose(inStream, outStream);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Drakos. I only need to encrypt it. I wont decrypt it for now. Were do you point to the file that you want  to encrypt?

Comment: `File input= new File(inDir, inFilename);` is the input file to encrypt, `File output= new File(outDir, outFilename);` is the encrypted output file

Comment: Thanks Drakos you helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [zip4jvm](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/zip4jvm)

```java
char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
ZipEntrySettings entrySettings =
             ZipEntrySettings.builder()
                             .encryption(Encryption.AES_256, password)
                             .build();
ZipSettings settings =
                  ZipSettings.builder()
                             .entrySettingsProvider(fileName -> entrySettings)
                             .build();

Path zip = Paths.get("dest.zip");
Path srcDir = Paths.get("/srcDir");
ZipIt.zip(zip).settings(settings).add(srcDir);
```